# Flutter Riverpod - Checkbox with StateNotifierProvider and a Model, how does it work

Tags: flutter, dart, state, riverpod

I have a model which is a Blueprint to fill before I am going to send it via HTTP. The Model contains a bool value:

```
class ReportBugModel {
  bool isReproductive;
  ReportBugModel({
    this.isReproductive = false,
  }) ;

  ReportBugModel copyWith({
    bool? isReproductive,
}) {
    return ReportBugModel(
      isReproductive: isReproductive ?? this.isReproductive,
    );
  }
}
```

Then I have a StateNotifer with this Model:

```
class FillReportBugModelNotifier extends StateNotifier<ReportBugModel> {
  FillReportBugModelNotifier() : super(ReportBugModel());
  void toggleReproductive() {
    print("inside toggle");
    state = state.copyWith(isReproductive: !state.isReproductive);
  }
}

final fillErrorModelProvider = StateNotifierProvider<FillReportBugModelNotifier, ReportBugModel>((ref) {
  return FillReportBugModelNotifier();
});
```

And inside my widget there is the problem now:

```
class _AdditionalInfoScreenState extends ConsumerState<AdditionalInfoScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isChecked = ref.watch(fillErrorModelProvider).isReproductive;
    print(isChecked);

 return Stack(
      children: [
//...
CheckboxListTile(
value: isChecked,
 onChanged: (bool? value) {
                         ref.read(fillErrorModelProvider.notifier).toggleReproductive();
                        },
```

As you can see, I added a print statement and this is the output after a HotRestart and two clicks on the checkbox (Expected output should be: false -> true and then true -> false":

```
"Restarted application in 232ms.
false
false
false
inside toggle
true
false
inside toggle
true"
```

So it's a strange behavior, I can't explain, like It's toggling extremely fast, but I only click once. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Widget rebuild is **not** that simple. There are a lot of factors that triggers the `build` method

Answer (score 0):

Make your `ReportBugModel` model immutable and repeat the steps. The `StateNotifier` must be based on immutable data, that is, that has `final` fields in its model, and the state change is based on a completely new object. For easier implementation, use the `freezed` package as this will generate the `copyWith` methods and the correct `hashCode`/`operator ==` for you.